# How do I auto-blank text console on laptop?

Tags: boot, command-line, grub2

How do I set up the console of the laptop to auto-blank after X minutes. I want to set this natively to the console, not a logged in terminal, because I may not log into it very often, and it may be sitting at a login prompt most of the time.

I would like the console to wake up and display when a key is pressed, and go back to powersave/blank mode after X minutes.

I can't believe it's so hard to find this -- I've been looking for some time. This is something that I got used to on NetBSD and FreeBSD as just a normal configuration parameter for the console. Surely it has to be possible.

I've already tried a few different things.  Most of them are based on explicitly manipulating the display or terminal settings.  This should be automatic.  I've tried using this in my grub config, but it seems to have no effect:
`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="consoleblank=60 maybe-ubiquity"`

This is on Ubuntu 18.04.4.

Answer (score 0):

The setting is in Settings → Power → Power Saving → Blank Screen then set time before screen blanks.

[image]